# profile picture appears in gchat but nowhere else

Tags: sms

Has anyone else had problems with their gmail profile pictures only appearing in the gchat message threads, but NOT when sending text messages through the Google Nexus S to other cell phones??

I thought that I had my phone synced up with my gmail account, so I don't know if I've missed a step.

Answer (score 1):

When I send SMS to another phone, it's not sent as my Google profile, eg. example@gmail.com, but as my number, eg. +123456789.

If you add your own number to your contacts, and then add profile picture, you will see it in SMS chat.

Answer (score 0):

Dont think the gmail profile picture and the sms picture will sync up. When you are in an sms chat try pressing your own picture and updating it with a picture of you.